# How can I send error data to me when my app crashes?

Tags: java, android, error-reporting

I would like to transmit the Stacktrace to me whenever my app crashes. If an app is uploaded to Google Play and it crashes there is an option to report the error, but very few people actually do that because it takes time. So I want to find a way around and make the app send the full stacktrace to me so I can solve bugs.

The setup has to be easy to implement. I thought about using Google Analytics, but that would require try-catch statements everywhere with the GA setup in each of them and it would be hard to set up and prevent ANR because nullpointers occur somewhere in the code.

How do I do something like that?

Comment: http://www.acra.ch/

Comment: You are looking some as Crashlytics? https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary

Comment: @CommonsWare How would I go about reporting errors? How does acra do it? Does the user have to do anything or is it all automatic?

Comment: ACRA is configurable for how it handles crashes. Your questions are covered in the ACRA documentation. I also [released my book chapter on ACRA under a Creative Commons license](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/17/book-excerpt-crash-reporting-acra.html), and it covers your questions as well.

Comment: I used Crashlytics for my apps. Crashlytics shows you the stacktrace, also you can add variables such a User Id, User Email, username.

Comment: @CommonsWare As of the installation; Is there a separate class that extends Application or is that class supposed to be the main class?

Comment: If you already have a subclass of `Application` that you are using, you should be able to just add the ACRA bits to it. If you are not using a custom `Application` subclass, you can add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use ACRA since its more configurable.

ACRA can be downloaded from https://github.com/ACRA/acra and it runs on your own server (if you have one).

**How does it report crashes?**

It has three ways to send the crash reports to you.

*First* - Automatically send the crash report without the user's choice

*Second* - Give the user the choice to send the crash report or not (notification).

*Third* - Automatically restart the application and then give the user a choice to send the report or not.

And a few more.

**Why use it?**

Compatible with Android 2.2 upwards.

Crash reports are way more detailed.

You can add your own variables and debug traces.

Error reports besides crash reports (if the application doesn't crash, error reports can be sent).

Its self-hosted.

Doesn't require Google Play to function.

If no network connection is present, the reports are sent later on when there is a network connection.

**The only server-side requirement they have is that its built around CouchDB, if your host doesn't support CouchDB, then there are a few free (and paid) external CouchDB hosts.**